# $stateParams is not refreshing. Wasted a lot of hours. Help needed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm developing my first application. It have worked really good, but now I'm stuck with an issue related to $stateParams.

I'm developing an app which requires login and logout. And have a url in this format:
 '#/tab/profile/{{userId}}'

I have a tab to show the user profile. It should read the ID from the url, and render this user.

If I login with an user, the profile is rendered correctly. But when I log out and then log in with other user, It still shows the first user profile. The $stateProvider variable, it still have the previous value.

I recorded this short video to explain my problem.

https://youtu.be/d4U1j3gKKt4

And below is my source code.

This is really driving me crazy. What should I do? Thanks a lot!

```
$stateProvider   
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  .state('tab.profile', {
    url: '/profile/:userIdInUrl',
    views: {
      'tab-profile': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

This is the tabs code. As showed in the video, the value is correctly updated:

```
  <!-- Profile Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Profile" icon-off="ion-ios-person-outline" icon-on="ion-person" href="#/tab/profile/{{userId}}">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

And this is my 'ProfileCtrl' code:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($http, $scope, $stateParams) {

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {      
    console.log('$stateParams:');
    console.log($stateParams);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. I finally managed to solve it.

I added this method:

```
  $scope.goToUserProfile = function(){
    $state.go('tab.profile', { userIdInUrl: AuthService.userId() });
  };
```

And changed my tabs code to this:

```
  <!-- Profile Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Profile" icon-off="ion-ios-person-outline" icon-on="ion-person" ng-click="goToUserProfile()">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-profile"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

Have a nice week!